# Windows 10 File Explorer won't open a folder that is minimized

Tags: windows-10

I just upgraded to Windows 10 yesterday. The File Explorer has new behavior that I want to behave like it did in Windows 7. Here are the steps to reproduce:

1. create a folder on desktop
2. open the folder in the file explorer by clicking it
3. minimize the desktop with Microsoft button + 'D'
4. click the folder on the desktop again

Expected: the clicked folder opens in the same file explorer that was minimized (this is Windows 7 default behavior).

Actual: the clicked folder does not open. It stays minimized. The only way to access it is to go to the task bar and click it there. Annoying! Especially when there are 20+ folders minimized and collapsed.

I checked in Explorer options and I don't see anything that would allow me to modify this behavior.

Comment: The behavior on Windows 7 is strange as well. I have explorer set to open windows maximised. When I click the desktop icon again it restores the window maximised and then immediately changes it to it's non-maximised state.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know what exactly you did, but I just tried it on my windows 10 laptop and it worked just fine.
Although, the laptop had windows 10 natively, so it wasnt upgraded. But even then I dont see a problem, I had my main computer upgraded and the shortcut with re-opening works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered both the issue and the solution.
A popular program that I enjoy, titled "SYSINTERNALS DESKTOPS.EXE", running as background service at startup is the culprit. It doesn't work with WINDOWS 10.

The solution is to uninstall it. Then reboot.